# Reactjs: programmatically focusing on a programmatically generated input

Tags: reactjs, focus

I have an app that renders an editable table, with several input elements per row. Since the table is populated with user entries, it can be of variable length. Some user entries into the table would be invalid. When an entry is invalid, I want to display an alert that says, "You entered invalid data" and then focuses the user on the input with an invalid entry.

Reading through the documentation, a ref would appear to be the best way of doing thing. However, all of the examples that I've found, whether from the React team or Stack Overflow, show a single input being bound to a single ref. Some action (typically clicking a button) is hard-coded to reference the specific ref, and everything works fine.

I'd like to determine the best means of accessing the relevant input upon an error. The 'best' way to do this appears to be creating an array of refs, then assigning a ref to each input-- but the docs also make a point of saying to use refs sparingly, and this feels like a gross misuse of refs.

I'd prefer to do something like creating a single ref, then re-assigning it to whichever input most recently updated. Every time the user loses focus, it checks to see whether or not to force focus on the input with bad data. This feels like it has the potential to be an anti-pattern, especially since I cannot find any evidence of someone else implementing it.

I'd love to know the best way to tackle this problem, as I fear that neither of my ideas are good paths forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely not on an input single ref, but on a container ref. You always have the one container ref and whenever a user blurs on an input you have to get all the inputs from the container using `.querySelectorAll('input')`, find the invalid one and focus it.

```js
const {
  useState,
  useCallback,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
  useEffect
} = React;

const defaultUsers = [
  { id: 1, name: "User #1", email: "user1@gmail.com" },
  { id: 2, name: "User #2", email: "user2@gmail.com" },
  { id: 3, name: "User #3", email: "user3@gmail.com" },
  { id: 4, name: "User #4", email: "user4@gmail.com" },
  { id: 5, name: "", email: "user5@gmail.com" },
  { id: 6, name: "User #6", email: "user6@gmail.com" },
  { id: 7, name: "User #7", email: "user7@gmail.com" },
  { id: 8, name: "User #8", email: "" },
  { id: 9, name: "User #9", email: "user9@gmail.com" },
  { id: 10, name: "User #10", email: "user10@gmail.com" }
];

const App = () => {
  const tbodyRef = useRef();

  const focusNextInvalidInput = useCallback(() => {
    if (tbodyRef.current) {
      const inputs = tbodyRef.current.querySelectorAll("td > input");
      for (const input of inputs) {
        if (input.value.length === 0) {
          input.focus();
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }, [tbodyRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    focusNextInvalidInput();
  }, [focusNextInvalidInput]);

  const [users, setUsers] = useState(defaultUsers);

  const updateUserField = useCallback(
    (id, field, value) =>
      setUsers(
        users.map(user => (user.id === id ? { ...user, [field]: value } : user))
      ),
    [users]
  );

  const changeUserName = useCallback(
    (id, name) => updateUserField(id, "name", name),
    [updateUserField]
  );
  const changeUserEmail = useCallback(
    (id, email) => updateUserField(id, "email", email),
    [updateUserField]
  );

  const usersRows = useMemo(() => {
    return users.map(({ id, name, email }) => (
      <tr key={id}>
        <td>{id}</td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="text"
            onChange={e => changeUserName(id, e.target.value)}
            value={name}
            onBlur={focusNextInvalidInput}
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="email"
            onChange={e => changeUserEmail(id, e.target.value)}
            value={email}
            onBlur={focusNextInvalidInput}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));
  }, [users, changeUserEmail, changeUserName, focusNextInvalidInput]);

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody ref={tbodyRef}>{usersRows}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/focus-invalid-input-react-o4qy7).

Comment: Thanks very much for the input. So the goal is essentially to give a ref to the overall table, then search through every single child on each blur to find the invalid data. When we find that invalid data, then we can update accordingly. And we're using useCallback and useMemo because we shouldn't need to be bothered by all but one of the fields.

Thanks very much for this! It's still a little fuzzy, but that's everything until you try it! I appreciate the assistance!